# ¿Como creo una pantalla de bloqueo con cronometro?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy buscando ayuda porque he estado haciendo un proyecto el cual es una pantalla de bloqueo con un temporizador en donde tiene que abrirse una ventana con una cuenta regresiva que previamente devia ser ajustada, a que me refiero:
Un ejemplo es que si coloco: 2 minutos deveria aparecer la ventana de cuenta regresiva y cuanto esto acabe se puede volver a colocar otra cuenta.`introducir el código aquí`
Este a sido mi avance:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def times():
current_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
clock.config(text=current_time,bg="black",fg="green",font="Arial 50 bold")
clock.after(200,times)

def validar():
if entrada1.get()== "123":
    abrirv2()
else: 
    messagebox.showwarning("Lo siento", "clave incorrecta")

def abrirv2():
ventana.withdraw()
win=tk.Toplevel()
win.geometry("900x900")
win.configure(background="dark blue")
win.title("Ventana 2")

e3=tk.Label(win,text="Tomate un tiempo",
bg="orange", fg="white")
e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)

boton2=tk.Button(win,text="ok", command=win.destroy)
boton2.pack(side=tk.TOP)
def cerrarv():
ventana.destroy()


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Ventana 1")
ventana.geometry("900x900")

ventana.configure(background= "dark blue")
ventana.title("Reloj digital con Tkinter")
clock=Label(ventana,font=("times",50,"bold"))
clock.pack(pady=25,padx=100)
times()

digi=Label(ventana,text=" Hora Actual",font="times 24 bold",fg="red")
digi.pack()

e1=tk.Label(ventana,text="Password:",bg= "dark turquoise",fg="white")
e1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
entrada1=tk.Entry(ventana)
entrada1.pack(fill=tk.X,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)

boton3=tk.Button(ventana,text="Validar password",fg="blue",command=validar)
boton3.pack(side=tk.TOP)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Por cierto tambien coloque un inicio de secion en base a que solo se pueda colocar una cuenta si se tiene la contraseña pero me falta el registrase y solo he colocado una simple clave de axceso.
Si alguien me podria ayudar, lo agradeceria

Comment: Importa la librería time y después usa su superpoder time.sleep()

Comment: Revisa la indentación del código que has pegado. Es incorrecta y no está claro dónde terminan las funciones